# Read python pickle with scala

Tags: python, scala, pickle

I inherited a database with values stored as Python pickled objects. Is there a way to unpickle these values in Scala (without calling Python internally) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you'd need to call python internally, because pickle allows classes to run arbitrary code on unpickling. (Do a search for "python pickle security" and you'll find a lot of [interesting discussions](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/03/exploiting-pickle/) about why this means you shouldn't unpickle from untrusted sources.)

I suspect it could be done for more common cases, though, if there's nothing particularly unusual in your pickled data. [This simliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794750/read-python-pickle-data-stream-in-android) has an answer suggesting a Java library called [Pyrolite](https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why it does not exist. I read about Pyrolite indeed.