# How to read using cPickle in jython

Tags: java, python, pickle, jython

I have a use case to read a Python object serialized using pickle in java. I was hoping to do this by using pickle in jython. Can someone give a small example of how this can be accomplished.

Comment: `cpickle` does not exist in Python 3.x

Comment: @martineau ok but what about 2.7. can you give me an example using that

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You have pickled some object and want to unpickle it in Java?

Comment: Doesn't jython include a `pickle` module? Why exactly do you want to use `cpickle`?

Comment: No jython latest version is 2.7.2 and it only has cPickle which is not in Python 3.x

Comment: @user8408080 Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do, but so far I don't see any way that is possible

Comment: Do you know, which protocol version your file is pickled with?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794750/read-python-pickle-data-stream-in-android/21801219#21801219) looks promising

Comment: In Python 3, `cPickle` was renamed `_pickle` — see [What difference between pickle and \_pickle in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191859/what-difference-between-pickle-and-pickle-in-python-3).